# Meteor: Temporally persist local collection when using it in different files

Tags: javascript, meteor, collections

I have a file created on a custom route that I will use for local collections.

This file is under **imports/localDb/** and is named **patients.js**:

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';

const PatientsLocal = new Mongo.Collection();

export default PatientsLocal;
```

What I'am doing is to import this file everytime that I need to do an operation (Insert, fetch, ...)

So for example, I have in a file:

```
import PatientsLocal from '../../../localDb/patients';

// ...

PatientsLocal.insert(patient);
```

The issue is :

When I have to do an operation I import the **patients.js** file, so the file runs entirely again and the collection is instantiated another time, so I can't insert an object in one file and fetch it on another.

What can I do to persist the collection during the runtime to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be fine by exporting it as const:

```
export const PatientsLocal = new Mongo.Collection();
```

However, there is more to think about: The module contains both definitions and instantiation code. A good practice is to decouple instantiation from definition.

A possible workaround would be to export a sort of context Object that contains several static properties that define the overall `Patients` context and decorate it on startup with properties that have to be instantiated:

*imports/local/patients.js*

```
export const Patients = {
  name: 'patients',
  collection: null,
  // other definitions...
}
```

Then in your startup code you instantiate the Collection **once**:

*client/main.js*

```
import { Patients } from '../imports/local/patients'
Patients.collection = new Mongo.Collection()
```

(note that this could be moved into an own startup module file)

and in your runtime code you import the context instead of the collection:

```
import { Patients } from '../../../local/patients'

// ...

Patients.collection.insert(patient)
```

Note that these are just a few examples of how to approach this problem. Others may include using the `global` namespace (which is discouraged but not prohibited) or some sort of registry class that keeps track of all the instances of the collections (like `dburles:mongo-collection-instances` which is a great package but accesses collections via `name` which is not defined on local collections).